# Is there a way to find a website hardware architecture (e.g cluster, cloud, web server, application server..etc)?

Tags: web, hardware

Is there a way to find a website hardware architecture (e.g cluster, cloud, web server, application server..etc) ?

Comment: For a particular site?  Or just in general?  Can you elaborate?

Comment: For a general site, for example if i wish to know how many servers are in stackoverflow.com, do they use F5, or cluster ..etc

Comment: You could try asking the webmaster of the site. Generally, I doubt they would tell you though!

Answer (score 0):

You can make guesses based on various details of the site, sort of a forensic investigation based on circumstantial evidence.  But (at least as far as I know) there's no way, from an end-user perspective, so determine the server-side architecture of a website.  The nature of the web creates a physical abstraction layer between the client and the server which obscures this information.

To give an example, if a high availability site has a production issue and fails over to a backup site (which is hosted on a different setup, such as with fewer servers or on different hardware), there *shouldn't* be a way for a client to even notice that anything happened, let alone retrieve the technical details of the fail-over.

When you're making a request to a website, you're essentially contacting a facade which "does some magic" behind the scenes and responds to the request.  All you can see is the facade.